# Set option of the 2nd Select based on the 1st Select

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have 2 select option

Select 1

```
<select id="header_mselect" name="header_mselect" class="form-control col-tablefont">
    <option selected="true" value="0">Select</option> 
    <option value="1">Approved</option>
    <option value="2">Disapproved</option>
    <option value="3">Hold</option>
</select>
```

Select 2

```
<select id="footer_mselect" name="footer_mselect" class="form-control col-tablefont">
    <option selected="true" value="0">Select</option> 
    <option value="1">Approved</option>
    <option value="2">Disapproved</option>
    <option value="3">Hold</option>
</select>
```

And this my code in header change

```
$('#header_mselect').on('change', function() {
    var svalue = $('#header_mselect :selected').val();
    var stext = $('#header_mselect :selected').text();
    $('#footer_mselect').find('option[text="' + stext + '"]').val();
});
```

My problem here is that i want to set the value or the option of 2nd select based on 1st select during selecting the option on the 1st one but its not working whats wrong?

Comment: Sure, this looks good now. Check out the answers below and accept whichever suits your needs best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try select the element with the desired `value` directly rather than using a loop (and use the proper selector; you have no `orderselect` in your code):

```js
$('#header_mselect').on('change', function() {
  var svalue = $('#header_mselect :selected').val();
  var stext = $('#header_mselect :selected').text();
  $('#footer_mselect > option[value="' + svalue + '"]').prop('selected', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="header_mselect" name="header_mselect" class="form-control col-tablefont">
  <option selected="true" value="0">Select</option>
  <option value="1">Approved</option>
  <option value="2">Disapproved</option>
  <option value="3">Hold</option>
</select>

<select id="footer_mselect" name="footer_mselect" class="form-control col-tablefont">
  <option selected="true" value="0">Select</option>
  <option value="1">Approved</option>
  <option value="2">Disapproved</option>
  <option value="3">Hold</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select the second select box option using

```
$('#footer_mselect').find('option[text="' + stext + '"]').prop('selected', true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the value of the first to the second, since both of the dropdowns share the same set of values.

1. Get the selected option's value using `val()` on the first dropdown itself.
2. Set the value to the second dropdown using `val()` again.

Find a working demo below:

```js
$('#header_mselect').on('change', function() {
  var svalue = $(this).val();
  $('#footer_mselect').val(svalue);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="header_mselect" name="header_mselect" class="form-control col-tablefont">
  <option selected="true" value="0">Select</option>
  <option value="1">Approved</option>
  <option value="2">Disapproved</option>
  <option value="3">Hold</option>
</select>
<select id="footer_mselect" name="footer_mselect" class="form-control col-tablefont">
  <option selected="true" value="0">Select</option>
  <option value="1">Approved</option>
  <option value="2">Disapproved</option>
  <option value="3">Hold</option>
</select>
```